# Datatable displays different data for Date column then database query does

Tags: jquery, datatable

I need to display last 40 days data on my page.
When running the query with the following statement:
`... 
 and CreateDate > getdate() - 40
 ...`

I get the correct data for CreateDate: 2017-01-11 14:51:43.150

When trying to get the same data using javascript I'm getting the data with the different date of 12/21/2016 13:42:56:

```
for (var i = 0; i < MyObject.length; i++) {
     if (MyObject[i][0].toString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") > Date.today().add(-40).days().toString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")) {
          aData[aData.length] = MyObject[i];
     }
}
```

I noticed that, when I run `select getdate() - 40` in SQL, I get 2016-12-21 18:27:25.877 which is less then my CreateDate. That's why I get 2017-01-11 14:51:43.150 in SQL.

However, when trying to get the same record using javascript:

`Date.today().add(-40).days().toString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")`, this statement produces: "12/21/2016 00:00:00" date.

That's why my `if` logic does not compare the correct data.
Instead of comparing 2016-12-21 13:42:56.123 with 2016-12-21 18:27:25.877,
it compares 2016-12-21 13:42:56.123 with 12/21/2016 00:00:00.

That makes the left value greater then the right value and therefore it displays the corresponding object.

I need to format the right hand value, so the date is 2016-12-21 18:27:25.877

How can I format `Date.today().add(-40).days().toString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")` to get the correct data to compare with?

Comment: But I need to get the date that is greater then getDate() - 40. And the date: 2017-01-11 14:51:43.150 is exactly between getDate() - 40 and getDate()

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.
I think the problem was in comparing string values not the actual dates.

Here is the solution:

```
var createDate = new Date(MerchantNotes[i][0]);
var forty = new Date();
forty.setDate(forty.getDate() - 40);

if (createDate > forty)
{
   //the logic goes here
}
```